# How to swap implicit JSON formatter for two controller endpoints in Scala Play

Tags: json, scala, playframework, implicit

I have a Scala Play endpoint that returns complex JSON configuration that has a structure like this:

```
Configuration    
|__ DBConfig
    |__ SecretDef
|__ SecondDBConfig
    |__ SecretDef
|__ AuthConfig
    |__ SecretDef
```

There's more than 20 implicit formatters used to serialize this configuration and one for SecretDef looks like:

```
  implicit val fSecretFormat: Format[SecretDef] = new Format[SecretDef] {
    override def writes(o: SecretDef): JsValue = 
      Json.toJson(o.value)

    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[SecretDef] = ???
  }
```

I need to implement another version of the same endpoint that returns whole configuration but with defrent version of writes for SecretDef:

```
  implicit val fSecretFormatDec: Format[SecretDef] = new Format[SecretDef] {
    override def writes(o: SecretDef): JsValue = 
      Json.toJson(decryptWithAES(o.value))

    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[SecretDef] = ???
  }
```

Within controllers I'm importing all implicits, but I have a problem to swap implicit formatter for SecretDef in particular action for V2 endpoint.

Something like this would be ideal, but it doesn't work:

```
      Action.async { implicit request =>
        implicit val fSecret: Format[SecretDef] = utils.SecretFormatters.fSecretFormatEnc
        for {
          config <- configRepo.getConfig()
        } yield Ok(Json.toJson(tenant))
      }
```

**SOLUTION:**
Based on the comment made by Gaël J, I've came up with the following solution:

```
trait Formatters {
  implicit def getSecretDef: Format[SecretDef]
  // all other wrapping implicits as def

}
object JsonFormatters extends Formatters {
  override implicit def getSecretDef: Format[SecretDef] = SecretFormatters.fSecretFormat
}

object JsonFormattersV2 extends Formatters {
  override implicit def getSecretDef: Format[SecretDef] = SecretFormatters.fSecretFormatDec
}
```

Then, import needed implicit within action context.

Comment: Can't you just build another instance of `SecretDef` or another case class? Having two `Format` means you will have to either duplicate a lot of things or make the `Format` of the outer class a `def` that takes a `Format[SecretDef]` as input.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That actually helped me to come to the solution. I converted all outer implicits to def and created a 2 object that implement common trait with 2 different versions of SecretDef formatter.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to define your `Format[SecretDef]` inside the `SecretDef` object.

Something like this:

```
class SecretDef { ... }

object SecretDef {
   implicit val format: Format[SecretDef] = Json.format[SecretDef]
}
```

Then will not need to define on each route the `implicit Format[SecretDef]` and your code will be more consistent to have your class definition and JSON format in the same file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm not sure how it would solve the problem. I need to use 2 formaters for SecretDef (one that returns encrypted value and second one that returns decrypted value). I need to use one of those 2 depending on context.